# Can send var from javascript to use it in JSTL c:set?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Is there any way that i can get a variable that i've declared in JavaScript Function to the JSTL tags  ?

Javascript

```
var abc = document.getElementById('asdf').value;
```

here is the JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" id="asdf" value="onetwothree" />
```

and i want to declare the C:set from the JavaScript

```
<c:set var="ex" value="${abc}" />
```

The purpose it to get `"ex"` variable with the value "onetwothree".

Sorry for the rough explanation. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to access a component from jsp in javascript and use javascript variable to populate a component in jsp? Can't you do it directly, without using javascript?

Comment: what do you want `ex` variable for? does it require any client input?

Comment: the next step is  I'm gonna use the 'ex' variable to c:if. I Thought i can't use input type hidden directly to the jstl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it other way. it is possible to access a variable declared in `jsp` from javascript using below code

```
<c:set var="ex" value="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var abc = '${ex}';
</script>
```

but other way around as you mentioned above **is not possible**

If you are looking to modify DOM based on what is provided in `input` box then I would suggest to use code like below (in javascript)

```
var abc = document.getElementById('asdf').value;

// assuming you want to print this value in a label
document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = abc;
```

In short **if you want to do any change in DOM based on client input, do it through javascript** instead of relying on JSP

Comment: hi, but is there any way that i can use the variable from javascript and use it in jstl c:if?

Comment: no that's not possible. `jstl` is executed on server before your `javascript` code. you can though refresh the page with your javascript variable as request parameter in URL and then read it in jstl. your url will be like `myurl/abc.htm?jsVar=abcValue` and then read in jstl as `<c:set var="ex" value="${param.jsVar}">`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access JSTL tags from Javascript, simply because those tag exists only server side (client side they are replaced by plain HTML).

You can always send the javascript var as request parameter, then use it server side.